# Why do adonis2 and capscale give different anova results?

Tags: r, vegan

first time poster here. r sig ecology won't accept my post, and I haven't been able to contact Jari Oksanen directly.

My question regards what appears to be a discrepancy between adonis2 and capscale (package vegan 2.6-2) in the calculations of the sums of squares and thus the F statistics in the permanova tables.

I am currently using R v 4.2.0.

I used the adonis2 function to run a one-way permanova to examine differences in tree leaf litter species composition among three sites that were treated differently. The analysis was based on Bray-Curtis distances.

> `area.differences=adonis2(tree.leaf.species~Area, method="bray",data=area)`

When I call the result, I get the following permanova table.

|  | Df | SumOfSqs | R2 | F | Pr(>F) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Area | 1 | 4.0083 | 0.6082 | 20.977 | 0.001 |
| Residual | 27 | 2.5796 | 0.39157 |  |  |
| Total | 29 |  | 1.000 |  |  |

To get relevant sample and species scores for an ordination of the results, I used the capscale function.

```
dbRDA.one.way.area=capscale(tree.leaf.species~Area, distance="bray", data=area)
```

I had thought that these two analyses were directly comparable and should give identical permanova table results. However, when I called for the anova table:

> `anova(dbRDA.one.way.area)`

I got the following result:

```
      Df      SumOfSqs     F       Pr(>F)
```

Model      1       4.0333      16.023  0.001
Residual  27       3.3981

Can someone please tell me what accounts for the discrepancy in the SS and F?

*** NOTE: WHEN I DO THESE SAME ANALYSES USING R V 3.2.4 vegan package 2.4-5, THERE IS NO SUCH DISCREPANCY IN THE ANOVA TABLES. WHAT HAS CHANGED?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: I could not quite read your unformatted text, and I'm not sure what was the problem. However `capscale` and `adonis2` are not comparable (and you shouldn't use `adonis`). `dbrda` and `adonis2` should be similar.

Comment: Hi Jari,  thanks for your reply. Sorry about the formatting issue.  For some reason, I had thought dbRDA and capscale did the same thing, but I see now that they use different approaches and could give difference answers with non-Euclidean distances. My preference was to do capscale because it gave species scores, whereas dbRDA did not, but I suppose I can calculate species scores using the wascores  function from the dbrda sample scores. Again, I appreciate your taking the time to clarify things for me.

Comment: @SteveBrewer See `?sppscores` also in {vegan} as one option to add them, but read the surrounding information in that page that Jari provides

Comment: Gavin, thanks. Yes, I had read that page and did try using sppscores, but I got a message saying that 'sppscores is not implemented yet.'